# Solve on SUM and AVG, Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query in SQL to Sum and Average values:

```
USE DBSTG_INT
GO

select distinct 
sum(a.EventoPrecioReg) as PrecioRegular,
sum(a.EventoPrecioVta) as PrecioVenta,
AVG(VTA_IUnidades) as Unidades,
SUM((a.EventoPrecioVta - a.EventoPrecioReg) * (AVG(VTA_IUnidades))) as Inversion
from EventoPrecioDeta a WITH (NOLOCK)
```

And when I execute it, it shows following problem:

> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 8 
>     Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

What I have done wrong and how can I solve it?

Comment: Is it possible you just confused the parantheses? `SUM(a.EventoPrecioVta - a.EventoPrecioReg) * AVG(VTA_IUnidades) as Inversion`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select distinct` doesn't make sense in this case.  Your problem is nested aggregates.  Perhaps you intend:

```
select sum(a.EventoPrecioReg) as PrecioRegular,
       sum(a.EventoPrecioVta) as PrecioVenta,
       AVG(VTA_IUnidades) as Unidades,
       SUM(a.EventoPrecioVta - a.EventoPrecioReg) * AVG(VTA_IUnidades) as Inversion
from EventoPrecioDeta a ;
```

Answer (score 1):

try like below dont need distinct

```
select  
sum(a.EventoPrecioReg) as PrecioRegular,
sum(a.EventoPrecioVta) as PrecioVenta,
AVG(VTA_IUnidades) as Unidades,
SUM(a.EventoPrecioVta - a.EventoPrecioReg) * AVG(VTA_IUnidades) as Inversion
from EventoPrecioDeta a
```